# This JavaScript Works Alone, But Not With Other JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this code from my programmer (outsourcing) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
     $('#notif-icons > li > a, #top-menu > li > a').click(function() {
         var clicked = $(this).next('.popup-notif');
         $('.popup-notif').not(clicked).fadeOut('fast');
         clicked.slideToggle('fast');
     }).toggle(function(){
        $(document).click(function() {
            $('.popup-notif').fadeOut('fast');
        });
        $('.popup-notif').click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
     }, function() {
     });
  });
</script>
```

that code works alone in plain HTML, but when I put into my codes, it won't work anymore and I think there's something wrong with that code. for example :

```
}, function() {
         });
      });
    </script>
```

I have no idea what that empty function() used for... could you guys please help me. because I'm not expert in JavaScript things... thanks!

**Update : this code used to display notifications. once "notif-icons" clicked, ".popup-notif" shows up and vice versa.

Comment: `toggle` takes multiple functions and each time a click event is triggered, it picks the next one (then loops).  So, the empty function means every other click, nothing happens.

Comment: Why is your "programmer" assigning a click event inside toggle (which is a click event)?

Comment: What "Won't work" about the code? Are you getting any errors in firebug or IE's console (hit f12 to open)? What is expected behavior and what is it doing instead?

Comment: @scrappedcola : I just edit my post. please check it out...

Comment: Okay, you described what it does. I still don't see a problem. "but when I put into my codes, it won't work anymore" *What* stops working?

Comment: Valid use of `toggle()` (though the blank function should have been left out). See http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/.

Comment: If by "your codes" you mean some kind of asynchronous genereated HTML markup you will need to change `$('#notif-icons > li > a, #top-menu > li > a').click(...);` to `$('#notif-icons > li > a, #top-menu > li > a').live("click", ...);`.

Comment: @Prusse: I would suggest `.on` instead (unless you are on an older version of jQuery).

Comment: *"...Works Alone, But Not With Other JavaScript"* So it works. But not with "other" JavaScript. But you left the "other" JavaScript out of the question. So it can't be answered.

Comment: @Rocket: Ok... I didn't check the jquery docs recently(don't use in work). I will change my suggestion to: If by "your codes" you mean some kind of asynchronous genereated HTML markup you will need to change `$('#notif-icons > li > a, #top-menu > li > a').click(...);` to `$(document).on('click', '#notif-icons > li > a, #top-menu > li > a', ...);`.

Answer (score 2):

When you say you 'put it in your codes' (why did you not use a 'z' there?!!), do you mean, when you copy it verbatim into a .js file? If so, you're not copying the `<script>` element into the .js file as well are you? JavaScript inline with HTML requires a `<script>` element, JavaScript in a .js file does not need `<script>` and `</script>` inside the .js file, only in the HTML that references the .js file

Answer (score 1):

<strike>The code isn't actually *that* bad.</strike> In this case, `toggle` is used as the event, and not the effect (see http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/). The two functions that are passed to it specify what to do on even and odd clicks of the `$('#notif-icons > li > a, #top-menu > li > a')` elements.

<strike>The JavaScript code looks like it will do what it's supposed to do;</strike> check to see that your HTML is correct. Make sure that `$('#notif-icons > li > a, #top-menu > li > a')` matches the correct elements, and that there is a `.popup-notif` element placed after *every* `'#notif-icons > li > a, #top-menu > li > a'`. If you don't put it every time, the popups may mysteriously disappear when you click on menu items (the fix for this is left as an exercise to the reader).

Also, make sure that the JavaScript is being loaded *after* the relevant HTML is loaded; either put it at the bottom of your file, or wrap it in `$(document).ready(function(){[code goes here]})`.

Unfortunately, you didn't provide enough detail in your question for me to provide a more specific answer; JavaScript needs context (i.e. give us the relevant HTML too).

I don't know what your personal level of skill is with JavaScript; but a quick tip: outsourced work generally results in working, but not great, code. It's a good idea to have a solid grasp of whatever technologies they're using so you can understand and use the work that they did, and not rely on them completely.

Comment: The problem I have with the code is that, click handlers are being bound **each** time the click event (in `toggle`) is fired.

Comment: Also `$(function(){` is the same as `$(document).ready(function(){`.

Comment: Yes, I retract my statement. The code sucks.